# Since I formatted my pc, I get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present..." error... How comes?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, security

Since I formatted my pc,I get this message when sending an ajax requestion itself calling a php file: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Is the server you are requesting something from a different host/domain/subdomain?

Comment: I'm using apache on my local computer. I guess that makes it from the same host right?

Comment: And you are running the file from `http://localhost/something` or `file:///path/to/something`? It should be the first, and AJAX requests then should use `http://localhost` too.

Comment: It does write: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/MTGComboFinder/ValidateEditDsr.php" ... Why so? I am not aware of having changed anything. Also, how can I make the thing works? thanks.

Comment: Well, first of all, PHP scripts loaded from `file:///...` are not run through the server, so they don’t execute. And then, as I said, you need to run everything—your PHP script, and your JavaScript—from the same domain, i.e. `http://localhost`.

Comment: @poke How am I supposed to do that? As I said, I only formatted my cpu. The code was left unchanged and I think the project and its files are all at the same location.

Comment: Well, the project may be in the same location, but you still need to run it through your xampp; i.e. start your Apache, and open the file with `http://localhost/MTGComboFinder/ValidateEditDsr.php` or something like that. (Also, you can’t format a CPU)

Comment: @poke I meant to say "pc". And thanks! It works now. I opened my main page by double clicking the html page rather than opening it via netbeans as usual, since a project was running on netbeans.

thx.

Answer (score 1):

- You've changed browser to one with a different security policy *or*
- You've started testing by loading files from your file system instead of your http server

Comment: I'm using the same browser and I'm loading my files from the same location.